# Crystal report prinjoblimit exceed error . tried diposal object increased regisry no use

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, crystal-reports, report

Hi All i am getting following error in crystal reports production. i have tried repordocument diposal. and increasing registry values both case is not working. attached error below
[image]

[image]

[EDIT]

please check below my code this my exact code scenario

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   Try
        If rpt IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each t As Table In rpt.Database.Tables
                t.Dispose()
            Next
            rpt.Close()
            rpt.Dispose()
            rpt = Nothing
            ' GC.Collect()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    'Session("RPTManagmentName") = Session("RPTManagmentName") & "  -  " & Session("RPTBranchName")
    rpt = New ReportDocument
    Select Case Request.QueryString("RPT")
        Case 6
            Dim Report As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
            Report.Load(Server.MapPath("Reports/RPTBalances.rpt"))
            Report.SetDataSource(Session("BalancesReportDataSet").Tables(0))
            Report.SetParameterValue("ManagmentName", Session("RPTManagmentName"))
            Report.SetParameterValue("BranchName", Session("RPTBranchName"))
            Report.SetParameterValue("AccountName", Session("RPTAccountName"))
            Report.SetParameterValue("  FromDate", CStr(Session("RPTFromDate")))
            Report.SetParameterValue("ToDate", CStr(Session("RPTToDate")))

            Session("report") = Report
      End Select

    CRVShow.ReportSource = rpt
    CRVShow.DataBind()

End Sub


Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
        Try
        If rpt IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each t As Table In rpt.Database.Tables
                t.Dispose()
            Next
            rpt.Close()
            rpt.Dispose()
            rpt = Nothing
            ' GC.Collect()
        End If

        If CRVShow IsNot Nothing Then
            CRVShow.ReportSource = Nothing
            CRVShow.Dispose()
            CRVShow = Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Try
        rpt.Close()
        rpt.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: anyone please reply?

Comment: Seriously you take a photo to your monitor instead of take a screenshot?

Comment: is this really matters ???

if yes i will explain .. this is happened in production server they shared me this from whatsapp.. so obviously took mobile snap hope u clear now... please try to help in rectify the issue now... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend moving your close/dispose/gc.collect code outside of that unload process. In other words:

1. Load report
2. Assign to Viewer Control
3. Show Report in Viewer Control
4. Close Viewer Control and Unload (completely)
5. Then close/dispose/gc.collect outside of any viewer control code

My guess is the viewer control is not completely closed when the report is being cleaned up.

Crystal is a very memory intensive process and very finicky.

Comment: can you please help me in this how to do this?

edited with my code.

Comment: Then close/dispose/gc.collect outside of any viewer control code 
please explain me how to do this i am new to crystal reports.